# функция возвращает None (python)

Tags: python, дерево

переменная x в методе search становится None, хотя на момент return self точно не None

```
    def delete(self, val):
        arr = []
        x = Tree.search(self, val)

        def collectVal(x, arr):
            if x is not None:
                if x.left is not None:
                    arr.append(x.left.val)
                    collectVal(x.left, arr)
                if x.right is not None:
                    arr.append(x.right.val)
                    collectVal(x.right, arr)
            return arr

        arr = collectVal(x, arr)
        print(arr)

    def search(self, val):
        if self.val == val:
            print("Success!", val, "найдено!")
            return self
        else:
            if val < self.val:
                if self.left is not None:
                    self.left.search(val)
                else:
                    print(val, "not found!")

            elif val > self.val:
                if self.right is not None:
                    self.right.search(val)
                else:
                    print(val, "not found!")
```

Comment: А на момент последней строчки функции?

Comment: ну когда я делаю return, self не является None'ом, так как я могу вызвать у нее метод val, который покажет ее значение как целое число

Comment: Вы делаете return только в одной ветви условия. Почему вы уверены, что условие else не выполняется? А если и выполняется, то функция ничего не возвращает => x = None.

Comment: Потому что print("Success!", val, "найдено!") отрабатывает

Comment: действительно, если добавить return в else, метод вернет не None, но как тогда у меня отрабатывает ```print("Success!", val, "найдено!") ``` я не понимаю

Comment: @ГришаБабилонов отрабатывает, возвращает тому, кто вызвал, а тот, который вызвал `self.left.search()`/`self.right.search()`, его игнорирует и не передаёт дальше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я вижу по коду функции вам необходимо найти точное совпадение:

```
def search(self, val):
    if self.val == val:
        print("Success!", val, "найдено!")
        return self
    else:
        print(val, "not found!")
        return self
```

в любом случае будет возвращено само значение объекта, но с точки зрения полезности я бы возвращал True/False. Здесь все зависит от требований. И так как над объектом класса не проводятся никакие действия, то и возвращать self смысла нет

```
def search(self, val):
    if self.val == val:
        print("Success!", val, "найдено!")
        return True
    else:
        print(val, "not found!")
        return False
```

**UPD: по условиям**
сам класс:

```
class Tree:

def __init__(self, val):

    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.val = val

def search_insert(self, val):

    if self.val:
        if val < self.val:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Tree(val)
            else:
                self.left.search_insert(val)
        elif val > self.val:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Tree(val)
            else:
                self.right.search_insert(val)
    else:
        self.val = val

def collectVal(self, obj):
    result = []
    if obj:
        result = self.collectVal(obj.left)
        result.append(obj.val)
        result = result + self.collectVal(obj.right)
    return result
```

пример вызова:

```
>>> from p import Tree as t
>>> r = t(20)
>>> r.search_insert(30)
>>> r.search_insert(24)
>>> r.search_insert(60) 
>>> r.search_insert(45)
>>> r.search_insert(1)  
>>> r.collectVal(r)     
[1, 20, 24, 30, 45, 60]
```

надеюсь это поможет

Comment: Над объектом будут производиться действия в методе delete. То есть мне нужно найти объект, с помощью метода search, вернуть его в метод delete, чтобы от него уже начать плясать. Вообще там целый класс, реализующий структуры дерева, так что использовать то что вы привели в блоке кода вряд ли получится.

Comment: напишите, что содержит объект класса, т. е. __init__

Comment: ```def __init__(self, val):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = val
```
Прошу прощения за кривость ответа, не знаю как исправить

Comment: конечно, разобраться сложно без поставленой задачи. Но функция `search` всегда возвращает `print("Success!", val, "найдено!")` потому что вы вызывете ее снова в ней же самой. Т. е. вы сравниваете либо с левым, либо с правым значением, при не равенстве `val` и `self.val`, что вам в итоге и возвращает success

Comment: будет проще, и укажите, что такое `Tree`

Comment: Если значение в дереве отсутствует, то выведется not found. Только что проверил

Comment: Tree - класс реализующий структуру дерева. Если элемент меньше корневого, то он идет в левую ветку, иначе в правую.

Comment: да, потому что ни справа, ни слева его нет

Comment: метод находит объекты, находящиеся в глубине дерева или обнаруживает их отсутствие, если дошло до конца и уперлось в None

Comment: Спасибо, Дмитрий!